# Page xhtml not displayed with WAS 8.0 , Richfaces 3 and JSF 1

Tags: jsf, websphere, richfaces

I have a web application made with Richfaces 3.3 and JSF 1 (using jsf-facelets-1.1.15.ar), deployed in our local WAS 8.0.0.
Pages are in xhtml and we have declaration namespaces standard:

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
```

When Websphere 8.0 starts, it's ok, when opening a page from local,
http://localhost:9080/Myapp/pages/home.jsf , we had an error :

viewhandler   E   Error Rendering View[/pages/home.xhtml]
                                 javax.el.ELException: /pages/home.xhtml: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ArrayList.get(java.lang.Byte)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:53)
....

Caused by: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ArrayList.get(java.lang.Byte)**
    at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:280)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:843)

With RAD we have set JRE preferences "WebSphere Application Server v8.0 JRE"
and the project has compiler JDK 1.5.

Page error with code jstl :  #{myBean.myList.get(indexRuntime).myProperty}

Does not find the get method of JAVA's Arraylist object ?!

With administrative console we have done: WebSphere enterprise applications > application_name > JSP and JSF options, under JSF implementation, selected Sun RI from the drop-down menu.

I'm going crazy. 
is a problem with JAVA versions on the pc?
Any Idea?

Thank you so much

Comment: What type is indexRuntime in that code you shared?  The argument for ArrayList.get() is an int, not a Byte.

Comment: I also tried in page with index 
 # {myBean.myList.get (1) .myProperty}
 and now says
 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ArrayList.get(java.lang.Long)
 at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:280)

Comment: Version of JRE present in folder "WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin" is 1.6.0 and project have compiler 1.5 jdk

Comment: Hi Jarid indexRuntime is a variable:  <c:forEach var="indexB" begin="0" end="#{bean.myList.size()-1}" step="2">

Comment: I solved removing RAD 8.0 and then installing RAD 9.6. Now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the issue [described by BalusC in this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31786923/3864977)

> In order to access a List item by a fixed index in EL, you need the
>   brace notation [] instead of performing a direct method call on
>   List#get(int).

Try accessing `myBean.myList` via bracket notation:

```
#{myBean.myList[indexRuntime].myProperty}
```

Comment: I solved removing RAD 8.0 and then installing RAD 9.6. Now it works, thanks